# Shortcut List script

Tags: powershell, foreach, user-profile, shortcut-file, export-csv

I've created a script that will read a list of usernames in a file named `Users.csv` and then search a network share for their user profile. It then reports on the shortcut target paths of said user profile and exports that to another `.csv`.

It works great when I use it per user but when I get it to report the data to the `.csv` file I can only seem to get it to report on the last user in my `Users.csv` and not each one. I was thinking it is because the export part of the script overwrites the `report.csv` for each user it runs and I need it to create a unique `report.csv` for each username. Anyone have any ideas?

```
$Users = (Get-Content C:\temp\Users.csv) -notmatch '^\s*$'

foreach ($User in $Users) {
    $Shortcuts = Get-ChildItem -Recurse \\UNCPATHTOUSERPROFILES\$User -Include *.lnk
    $Shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
    $data = foreach ($Shortcut in $Shortcuts) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            ShortcutName = $Shortcut.Name;
                  Target = $Shell.CreateShortcut($Shortcut).targetpath
                    User = $User
        }        
    }
    [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Shell) | Out-Null
}
foreach ($User in $Users) {
    $data | Export-Csv c:\temp\report.csv -NoTypeInformation 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should combine your two outer `foreach` loops, not only since they're iterating the same collection, but because the second loop is trying to use a variable, `$data`, created in the first loop.  Further, since `Export-Csv` is being called in a loop, you will need to pass the `-Append` parameter to prevent the output file from being overwritten each time.

```bsh
$Users = (Get-Content C:\temp\Users.csv) -notmatch '^\s*$'

foreach ($User in $Users) {
    $Shortcuts = Get-ChildItem -Recurse \\UNCPATHTOUSERPROFILES\$User -Include *.lnk
    $Shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
    $data = foreach ($Shortcut in $Shortcuts) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            ShortcutName = $Shortcut.Name;
                  Target = $Shell.CreateShortcut($Shortcut).targetpath
                    User = $User
        }        
    }
    $data | Export-Csv c:\temp\report.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation

    [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Shell) | Out-Null
}
```

You could also eliminate the `$Shortcuts` and `$data` variables in favor of using the pipeline...

```bsh
$Users = (Get-Content C:\temp\Users.csv) -notmatch '^\s*$'

foreach ($User in $Users) {
    $Shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell

    Get-ChildItem -Recurse \\UNCPATHTOUSERPROFILES\$User -Include *.lnk `
        | ForEach-Object -Process {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                ShortcutName = $_.Name;
                Target = $Shell.CreateShortcut($_).targetpath
                User = $User
            }
        } `
        | Export-Csv c:\temp\report.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation

    [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Shell) | Out-Null
}
```

...but note that `-Append` is still required.  Finally, you could rewrite the whole thing using the pipeline...

```bsh
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
try
{
    Get-Content C:\temp\Users.csv `
        | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch '^\s*$' } -PipelineVariable 'User' `
        | ForEach-Object -Process { "\\UNCPATHTOUSERPROFILES\$User" } `
        | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.lnk `
        | ForEach-Object -Process {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                ShortcutName = $_.Name;
                Target       = $Shell.CreateShortcut($_).targetpath
                User         = $User
            } `
        } `
        | Export-Csv c:\temp\report.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
finally
{
    [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Shell) | Out-Null
}
```

...so that `report.csv` is only opened for writing once, with no `-Append` needed.  Note that I am creating a single `WScript.Shell` instance and using `try`/`finally` to ensure it gets released.

In the event a user in `Users.csv` has no directory under `\\UNCPATHTOUSERPROFILES`, any of the above solutions and the code in the question will throw an error when `Get-ChildItem` tries to enumerate that directory.  You could fix that by checking that the directory exists first or passing `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to `Get-ChildItem`, or you could enumerate `\\UNCPATHTOUSERPROFILES` and filter on those that occur in `Users.csv`...

```bsh
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
try
{
    # Performs faster filtering and eliminates duplicate user rows
    $UsersTable = Get-Content C:\temp\Users.csv `
        | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch '^\s*$' } `
        | Group-Object -AsHashTable

    # Get immediate child directories of \\UNCPATHTOUSERPROFILES
    Get-ChildItem -Path \\UNCPATHTOUSERPROFILES -Directory -PipelineVariable 'UserDirectory' `
        <# Filter for user directories specified in Users.csv #> `
        | Where-Object { $UsersTable.ContainsKey($UserDirectory.Name) } `
        <# Get *.lnk descendant files of the user directory #> `
        | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.lnk -File `
        | ForEach-Object -Process {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                ShortcutName = $_.Name;
                Target       = $Shell.CreateShortcut($_).targetpath
                User         = $UserDirectory.Name
            } `
        } `
        | Export-Csv c:\temp\report.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
finally
{
    [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Shell) | Out-Null
}
```

Comment: You sir or maddam are a genius and a great teacher. Not only did you answer this but you taught me how to improve it. Thank you as i only started messing around with Powershell about a few months ago. I picked up a  powershell in month of lunches book so hopefully i can get a lot better as i go with that.